# libimobiledevice.a, libplist.a & libusbmuxd.a in a XCode macosx swift project

Tags: libimobiledevice

**Undefined symbols in libimobiledevice.a**

Installed the 3 libraries libimobiledevice, libplist & libusbmuxd with brew, followed your explanation, creating the 3 xcframeworks with [https://github.com/Schlaubischlump's](https://github.com/Schlaubischlump%27s) xcf-main/build_xcf.sh, brought them into XCode project under Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content, —deep & Disabled Library Validation(as was getting codesign errors), and ensured Header & Framework Search Paths are correct.
Error:
ld: Undefined symbols:
_ASN1_INTEGER_free, referenced from:
_pair_record_generate_keys_and_certs in libimobiledevice.a[x86_64]31
_pair_record_generate_keys_and_certs in libimobiledevice.a[x86_64]31
_pair_record_generate_keys_and_certs in libimobiledevice.a[x86_64]31
_ASN1_INTEGER_new, referenced from:
etc

Seems openssl is not linked to libimobiledevice.a, but not sure where to go from here. Trying to create a libopenssl.xcframework but running into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add libcryto.a & libbssl.a from brew installation, adding header and library paths to settings